# Log4j - file extension (.log) disappears after using DatePattern

Tags: java, log4j

I'm having a problem with my Log4j.xml file.
When I save a log file like that:

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="_dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss" />
    <param name="file" value="/logs/dailyschedule.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
                   value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} class:[%c] method:[%t] [%-5p] : %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

the file is ok, but has no file extension. Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Edit:
Before I saw Paul's answer, I was temporarily solved my problem by using a simple class for initializing my logger. It wasn't the best decision, but it can be usefull to someone with similar problem:

```
public class DomainLogger {

private Logger logger = null;

public DomainLogger(String directoryName, String fileName) throws Exception {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("_dd.MM.yyyy");
    String timeNow = sdf.format(new Date());

    String fullFilePath = System.getenv("DOMAIN_HOME") + 
            directoryName + "\\" + 
            fileName + timeNow + ".log";
    System.out.println("full filepath is " + fullFilePath);

    logger = Logger.getLogger(timeNow);
    //warning! different time will create a new file !!!

    PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout("%m%n");
    FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(patternLayout, fullFilePath);
    logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
}

public void writeLog(String logMessage) {
    logger.info(logMessage);
}
```

}

Comment: how can you tell that extension disappears? how do you check it? are you probably on windows and looking in the explorer with hiding extensions for known file types?

Comment: It is just a file - without any extension (not .txt or .log at the end as usual should be).
Anyway - I solved my problem, thanks to the comment of Paul.
But thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using log4j 1.x, we strongly recommend that you use [`org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) <sup>**1**</sup> instead of [`org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) (may lose messages, [Bug 43374](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43374)).

So the configuration of you appender can be:

```xml
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="activeFileName" value="/logs/dailyschedule.log" />
        <param name="fileNamePattern" 
               value="/logs/dailyschedule%d{_dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss}.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="conversionPattern" 
               value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} class:[%c] method:[%t] [%-5p] : %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Using this configuration, you will get finenames like the next: <sup>**2**</sup>

```
dailyschedule.log
dailyschedule_28.08.2014_14.57.45.log
dailyschedule_28.08.2014_14.57.46.log
dailyschedule_28.08.2014_14.57.47.log
dailyschedule_28.08.2014_14.57.48.log
dailyschedule_28.08.2014_14.57.49.log
```

---

*Notes*

1. In that case, you need to add the respective jar ([apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar)).
2. If you don't want the first filename (`dailyschedule.log`), drop the param `activeFileName` in the rolling policy.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is ok like that.