# Log4j RollingFileAppender filename prefix on rollover

Tags: log4j

Is there a way to set the fileName prefix for the rolled over file?

I use date for log files, i.e: **21-06-2017.log**
And have set the max file size to 10MB.
So when the file size reaches 10MB, rollover is performed and the current file is renamed to **21-06-2017.log.1** and so on...

I have a process which reads the files with extension **.log** and render it on UI

Also I'm using properties file and change the fileName programatically when my Spring loads.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

[EDIT]

Even if the RolledOver files are named as **21-06-2017_1.log**, that would be fine. Also any type of prefix is acceptable, the only end criteria is that the file name should end with ".log"

Comment: See this post.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609089/how-to-append-rolling-index-before-file-extension-in-log-filename

Comment: @arnabkaycee i found that property is for log4net and I'm using log4j. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Oops. My Bad. Try this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343866/log4j-file-extension-log-disappears-after-using-datepattern

Comment: @arnabkaycee Thanks again, but this post uses org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender (which is from apache extras package) instead of org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender. The disadvantage of this is I wont be able to set MaxFileSize and MaxBackupIndex on the appender.